# MySQL - Deleting old data; Select with index taking time

Tags: mysql, innodb, delete

I am a bit confused about 2 queries.

First query I am running on a 50m rows table by index on a `timestamp` row with a limit, I would expect the query to be immediate regardless of the size of the table, since I run on an index with small limit. Am I wrong?

```
SELECT 1
FROM indicators.fileso fo 
WHERE fo.lastSeen < NOW() - INTERVAL 2 MONTH
limit 100;
```

Create table:

```
CREATE TABLE `fileso` (
  `id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `hostId` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL COMMENT 'code',
  `sha256` binary(32) NOT NULL COMMENT 'meir',
  `fileName` varchar(150) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'meir',
  `fullPath` varchar(350) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'meir',
  `lastSeen` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `uniqueness` binary(32) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `uniqueness` (`uniqueness`),
  KEY `lastSeen` (`lastSeen`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1842469487 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Explain:
[image: pic1]

Second query when I select by timestamp row with index, with `order by desc limit 1` its immediate, but when I do `order by asc limit 1` it takes alot of time, dont understand that.

Immediate query:

```
SELECT 1
FROM indicators.fileso fo
ORDER BY fo.lastSeen DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

Takes time:

```
SELECT 1
FROM indicators.fileso fo
ORDER BY fo.lastSeen ASC
LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: `lastseen` is missing from the table definition.  Is the table partitioned?

Comment: Would the original query run faster if you added an `ORDER BY`?  (It rarely makes sense to have a `LIMIT` without an `ORDER BY`, and I think the optimizer missed that combo.)

Comment: @Rick James ,no, I manually removed column names as this table has about 30 columns and I wanted remove non-relevant columns for the question.. About your second question, no, because this query is meant for delete, I want to delete old records in batches..

Answer (score 1):

(This does not address your question directly; rather it addresses your goal of deleting old records.)

**Plan A**

You are talking about `DELETEing` "old" records.  Assuming you are removing "all" the old records, then `PARTITIONing` is an excellent way to do that.  `PARTITION BY RANGE(TO_DAYS)` by weeks.  Use `DROP PARTITION` (instantaneous and non-invasive) to get rid of the oldest week and `REORGANIZE PARTITION` to add a new partition.  [Details](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/partitionmaint).  It will take some downtime to initially partition your 50-million-row table.

**Plan B**

Alternatively, you can continually walk through the table, using the `PRIMARY KEY` for keeping track of where you are.  Find the 1000th row hence & delete any 'old' records.  Repeat.  [Details](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/deletebig).  And it does not need an index on `lastseen`; removing it could be an efficiency bonus.

Since the table is clustered on the PK(id), walking through the table is very efficient -- very little I/O for each step.  (For unknown reasons, your original solution was more I/O-bound than it should have been.)

Comment: thx for the answer, I will look into partitioning. Still I remain confused about  why this queries are acting this way :( I give you thumbs up, but still remain with my question